# how to overcome the situation when data stored as 0 instead of original

Tags: php, html, mysql

I created one table with decimal data types in mysql database. when i want to store some data it stores as 0 only. I tried by changing data types but no result. i am including the portion of php code

```
$que_sgpdetails = "INSERT INTO sgpa_details ( usn, sem_I, sem_II, sem_III, sem_IV, sem_V, sem_VI, sem_VII, sem_VIII ) VALUES ( :usn, :sem_I, :sem_II, :sem_III, :sem_IV, :sem_V, :sem_VI, :sem_VII, :sem_VIII )";
        $query_params5 = array( ':usn' => $_POST['usn'], ':sem_I' => $_POST['sem_I'], ':sem_II' => $_POST['sem_II'], ':sem_III' => $_POST['sem_III'], ':sem_IV' => $_POST['sem_IV'], ':sem_V' => $_POST['sem_V'], ':sem_VI' => $_POST['sem_VI'], ':sem_VII' => $_POST['sem_VII'], ':sem_VIII' => $_POST['sem_VIII'] );
        $statement5 = $db->prepare($que_sgpdetails);
        $result5 = $statement5->execute($query_params5);
```

Comment: Have you checked so there's really data in the `$_POST` array?

Comment: what kind of data are you storing there give us an example

Comment: are you using pdo, mdb2 or something else?

Comment: @orangepill, integer, float etc..

Comment: try to debug post fields use <code>echo '<pre>',print_r($_POST, true),'</pre>';</code>

Comment: Can you show the schema?More precisely how does the decimal column look?

Comment: @sakirAlam you should post and accept the answer if you think it will be helpful to other or delete the question if you don't